# Find multiple values within a Numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I am looking for a numpy function to find the indices at which certain values are found within a vector (xs). The values are given in another array (ys). The returned indices must follow the order of ys.

In code, I want to replace the list comprehension below by a numpy function.

```
>> import numpy as np
>> xs = np.asarray([45, 67, 32, 52, 94, 64, 21])
>> ys = np.asarray([67, 94])
>> ndx = np.asarray([np.nonzero(xs == y)[0][0] for y in ys]) # <---- This line
>> print(ndx)
[1 4]
```

Is there a fast way?

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For big arrays `xs` and `ys`, you would need to change the basic approach for this to become fast.  If you are fine with sorting `xs`, then an easy option is to use `numpy.searchsorted()`:

```
xs.sort()
ndx = numpy.searchsorted(xs, ys)
```

If it is important to keep the original order of `xs`, you can use this approach, too, but you need to remember the original indices:

```
orig_indices = xs.argsort()
ndx = orig_indices[numpy.searchsorted(xs[orig_indices], ys)]
```

Comment: if you don't need to keep track of what elements where found and which ones where not you can filter the output to get rid of all the indexes  beyond limits: ndx = [ e for e in np.searchsorted(xs,ys) if e<len(xs) ]

Answer (score 4):

In this kind of cases, just easily use [`np.isin()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) function to mask those elements conform your conditions, like this:

```py
xs = np.asarray([45, 67, 32, 52, 94, 64, 21])
ys = np.asarray([67, 94])

mask=xs[np.isin(xs,xy)]
print(xs[mask])
```

Comment: This question does not answer the the question. It ends up printing the value of `ys`. The variable `xy` is not defined and should be `ys`.