# Find index of multiple queries in a multidimensional numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am looking for a way to find indices of an array of queries in a multidimensional array. For example:

```
arr = np.array([[17,  5, 19,  9],
   [18, 13,  3,  7],
   [ 8,  1,  4,  2],
   [ 8,  9,  7, 19],
   [ 6, 11,  8,  5],
   [11, 16, 13, 18],
   [ 0,  1,  2,  9],
   [ 1,  7,  4,  6]])
```

I can find indices for one query:

```
np.where(arr==1)
# (array([2, 6, 7]), array([1, 1, 0]))
```

Is there any numpy solution to do this for multiple values replacing the following `for` loop?

```
for q in queries:
    np.where(arr==q)
```

If both the array and queries were one-dimensional, I could use `searchsorted` as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9566681/3349443) but it doesn't work for multidimensional arrays.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC you may try this:

```
In[19]:np.where((arr==4)|(arr==5))
Out[19]: (array([0, 2, 4, 7], dtype=int64), array([1, 2, 3, 2], dtype=int64))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the indices of each matching value by zipping the results of your `where` function and then using the `*` dereferencing operator.

```
arr = np.array([[17,  5, 19,  9],
                [18, 13,  3,  7],
                [ 8,  1,  4,  2],  # (2, 1)
                [ 8,  9,  7, 19],
                [ 6, 11,  8,  5],
                [11, 16, 13, 18],
                [ 0,  1,  2,  9],  # (6, 1)
                [ 1,  7,  4,  6]])  # (7, 0)

>>> zip(*np.where(arr == 1))
[(2, 1), (6, 1), (7, 0)]
```

I'm not sure what your intended output is, but you can use a dictionary comprehension to show the index location for a given set of numbers, e.g.:

```
>>> {n: zip(*np.where(arr == n)) for n in range(5)}
{0: [(6, 0)],
 1: [(2, 1), (6, 1), (7, 0)],
 2: [(2, 3), (6, 2)],
 3: [(1, 2)],
 4: [(2, 2), (7, 2)]}
```

Comment: Thanks but I wanted to get `np.where(arr == q)` for different values of `q`!

Comment: Do you want the indices for each value of `q` or for all of the values of `q`?

Comment: >>> ix = np.in1d(arr.ravel(), [1,8,18]).reshape(arr.shape) ...  

>>> found = np.array(list(zip(*np.where(ix)))) ... list is need in python 3.*