# Efficent way of finding rows matching a list of values

Tags: python, numpy

This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566592/find-multiple-values-within-a-numpy-array), but I couldn't find a way to adapt it in my case.

I have a pretty big `Nx3` matrix of integers. I need to find the list of rows matching a list of integers. The final goal is to filter the matrix to remove the rows containing one of these values.

Right now, the best I could come out with involves a `for` loop on my list of integers and `numpy.logical_and.reduce` to find the rows. I believe there must be a more efficient way, without having to go to a lower level language.

```
import numpy as np
matrix = np.random.randint(0,100000,(50000, 3))
values_to_find = np.random.randint(0,100000,10000)
matches = np.ones(len(matrix), bool)
for value in values_to_find:
    matches = matches & np.logical_and.reduce(matrix != value, axis=1)
new_matrix = matrix[matches]
```

What's the more efficient and elegant way?

Comment: So you want the rows that holds any one of the value of value_to_find?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach with [`np.isin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) ie

```
matrix[~np.isin(matrix, values_to_find).any(1)]
```

Comment: Rejoice! I accepted your solution because `timeit` don't seem to discriminate between the answers and yours is more readable. Thanks, didn't know about `np.isin` or the fact that I could specify an axis for `any`.

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to get the mask of matches across all rows with [`np.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) and then look for rows with any one match and then get the rest of the rows -

```
matrix[~np.in1d(matrix, values_to_find).reshape(matrix.shape).any(1)]
```

Comment: You are so fast. I came here with a solution you posted one.